# "No input file specified" Laravel 4 on Windows with IIS7

Tags: php, windows-7, iis-7, laravel, laravel-4

After installing **Laravel 4** on Windows 7 with **IIS7** I'm having a problem trying to access any route different than the main one (`/public/`).

Tryingn to access to this URL:

> public/users/

Generates this output on the website:

> No input file specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the URL rewriting.

A `web.config` file is needed instead of the current `.htaccess` file located in the `public` folder of Laravel.

It can be created it by importing the `.htaccess` file into the IIS7 Rewrite Module:
[image]

After applying the changes a `web.config` file will be generated in the main Laravel folder. 
Then it just needs to be moved into the `public` folder.

This is the content of the `web.config` file in case you want to generate it by yourself instead of using IIS7 for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```